# Angular Material dropdown select CSS

Tags: drop-down-menu, angular-material, angular-material2

[image][image]I have multiple div in each option for material dropdown which is getting  hide by another option how can i fix this.

Comment: can you share the code and a screenshot?

Comment: few details is getting hide by another option @theSwapnilSaste

Comment: Change all the DIVs and Ps to SPAN.